# CodeLite cmd promt closing immediatly after execution of code

Tags: c, codelite

I run the simplesest c hello world function in codelite just to see it works well

```
void main ( )
{
    
    printf("hello world\n");
    
}
```

the cmd promt opens for q brief momet and then closes down  immediatly.

what's wrong and how can I keep the cmd prompt without closing?

I excepct for the cmd prompt to stay

Comment: Two choices: a) open a command prompt first and run the code from there, or b) if running from IDE add an input to the end of the code, such as `getchar();` and then press Enter to end the program.

Comment: `system("pause");`

Answer (score 0):

From C11:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with
> int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent
> to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
> function as its argument; **reaching the } that terminates the main
> function returns a value of 0.** If the return type is not compatible
> with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is
> unspecified.

After the call to `printf`; control reaches the closing brace `}`, terminates `main`, and thus returns to the host environment with an exit status of `EXIT_SUCCESS`, or `0`.

---

Also note that it states:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be
> defined with a return type of int** and with no parameters:

```
int main (void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are
> local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your OS, so I will assume Windows.
Like other people mentioned, unless you add a call to getchr() or something similar, this is the expected behavior.

However, CodeLite does offer an option to pause your program once the execution is done.

- Right click on your project and open the settings
- Under the `General` tab, in the `Execution` section, make sure to check the option: `Pause when execution ends`
  (see attached screenshot)

What this does: Instead of running your program directly, CodeLite executes a small wrapper that will execute your program, and that wrapper pauses when its done.

[image]

HTH,
Eran